# Bring up scrollbar when <TextareaAutosize> is shrunk

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textarea, scrollbar, shrink

I am using a `<TextareaAutosize>` component from the [Material UI](https://mui.com/components/textarea-autosize/) Library in my React app, as such:

```
<TextareaAutosize 
   minRows="2"
   style={{resize: "vertical"}}
/>
```

This creates a textarea that autosizes based on the size of the content. I have styled it so that the user is only able to manually expand vertically.

The **current behavior** is that, when the user shrinks the textbox, there is no way to view the content out of sight. My **goal** is to bring up the scroll bar when the user shrinks the text area.

View [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/emptytextarea-material-demo-forked-tzlj4?file=/demo.js) to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: 'auto'` to the style attribute.

```js
<TextareaAutosize
  minRows="2"
  style={{ width: '50%', resize: 'vertical', overflow: 'auto' }}
/>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/emptytextarea-material-demo-forked-7jnvz)